# Add hyperkink to merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, hyperlink

I want to add an hyperlink to a range of merged cells. It is a relatively simple code. For instance:

```
Sheets("example").Hyperlinks.Add Range("A1:C2"), Address:=Sheets("").Range("").Value
```

My problem is that when I save the document as a PDF file, the hyperlink is only active on the extreme left of the range. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know Excel does not export any links into PDF, but if your PDF-Viewer detects a URL it will (probably) show it as link. But it will only convert the text of the URL into a link, because it doesn't know anything about the cells. • Please provide a proper [mcve] to reproduce the issue and tell how exactly you export to PDF and which application you use to view the PDF after export.

Answer (score 0):

The hyperlink you are adding is not in cells "A1:C2" but in "A1". With merged cells everything is in the first cell and only displayed over multiple cells. This workes fine but you might run in to trouble when yuou export.